# Node, GraphQL + MongoDB: Querying many-to-many relationships

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema

I am building a server with Express, GraphQL and MongoDB. I may need direction in my Mongo data modeling or GraphQl Schema setup, I am not sure. For this example, I have a User model and a Goal model. User's can have multiple goals and I planned on storing the goal id's on the User model. The user query is working, but goals returns null.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  ...
  goals: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Goal" }]
});

const GoalSchema = new Schema({
  goal: { type: String, required: true },
  users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
});
```

Below is the GraphQL Schema:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
    ...
    goals: {
      type: new GraphQLList(GoalType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Goal.find({ id: parent.goals });
      },
    },

  }),
});
```

What is the best way to go about this?